# How to pass a delimeted string of id's to tsql and process each

Tags: t-sql

I want to pass a comma delimeted string of PK's (int) into a sql stored proc. The proc would then perform an update statement on the table using a where clause including each of the PK's.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: there are a lot of answers about CSV processing using SQL, see [Split Function equivalent in tsql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697519/split-function-equivalent-in-tsql)

Comment: good point.. this one looks promising : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3806825/1132773

Answer (score 0):

We need more information. For instance if the update uses information from tables (joins) or of the rows are getting updated with the same information then you can use:

```
Update tableName
set ....
where tableName.id in @strOfIdsPassedIn
```